# Summarize information from one stored procedure in another stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that is not only huge, but very memory intensive. This first stored procedure is created for a detail report.  The second stored procedure calls the first stored procedure, places the information into a Temporary table and then selects the information from that temporary table and summarizes it.

Now, the second stored procedure doesn't need all of the information in the detail stored procedure, it only needs some of it.

Our DBA has called this approach reckless and has made other suggestions, such as "persist this to a real table so that it is run one-time per day".  This actually isn't going to happen because numerous users can run either report numerous times per day and for different date ranges.  His other suggestion was to SUM without the temp table, but I'm not sure how you select from one stored procedure only certain fields.

I have two questions:  How would I follow his second suggestion of SUM without the temp table and if that can't be done, does anyone have any suggestions on the best approach to use to summarize the needed data for the Summary report?

Both of these stored procedures are for separate reports.  One is for the detail and the other report is the summary.  The end users can run them for different stores and different time periods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not put the data in a view and hit the view from both stored procs?  This would reduce the complexity in both procs (but move it to the view).

Depending on the structure of your query you could possibly even create an indexed view which would create a persisted form of the data and allow you to make use of indexes.

Comment: How would this work when the end user can run it for any time period?

Comment: You would have to include any columns you need to filter by in the view.  So if there is a start or end date that you filter by, you would need to remove this from the where clause that populates your view and include it in your stored proc logic.

Answer (score 1):

If select in inner SP is quitely simple - try the approach that @Abe noticed

If the data cannot be presented in simple view, you have two ways:

1. Rewrite the outer proc in the manner of getting the only needed data without using your inner SP
2. Transfer only needed data thru outer temporary or persisted table

   - benefits of temp table - you can use indexes and no needs to maintain data which already not needed
   - benefits of persisted table just the same, except you can more fine tune it, tan temp table< **but** you have to bother about table cleanul and thus - have to introduce something like *session key* and *expiration date* and *outer cleanup*

Comment: I had a temp table, but the DBA said I couldn't use one.